# Seaborn Plotting Multiple Plots for Groups

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

How do I plot multiple plots for each of the groups (each ID) below with Seaborn? I would like to plot two plots, one underneath the other, one line (ID) per plot.

```
ID    Date           Cum Value  Daily Value
3306  2019-06-01      100.0     100.0
3306  2019-07-01      200.0     100.0
3306  2019-08-01      350.0     150.0
4408  2019-06-01      200.0     200.0
4408  2019-07-01      375.0     175.0
4408  2019-08-01      400.0     025.0
```

This only plots both lines together and can look messy if there are 200 unique IDs.

```
sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Daily Value",
             hue="ID", data=df)
```

Comment: Instead of a single plot with 200 lines, you want 2 plots with 100 lines each?

Comment: I just want two plots, one on top of the other for each unique ID, regardless if there are 2 or 200. One line for each plot. Thanks!

Comment: Then perhaps just make a separate figure per ID. I think it's going to be more trouble to try to get the sizing correct with 200 subplots: `for idx, gp in df.groupby('ID'): fig, ax = plt.subplots(); gp.plot(x='Date', y='Daily Value', ax=ax, title=idx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [3306, 3306, 3306, 4408, 4408, 4408],
                   'date': ['2019-06-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01'],
                   'cum': [100, 200, 350, 200, 375, 400],
                   'daily': [100, 100, 150, 200, 175, 25]
})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col = 'id')
g.map(plt.plot, 'date', 'daily')
```

which gives

[image]

but what happens if you have 200 ids?

Comment: Thanks @SchwarzeHuhn, how do I stack these two charts instead of having them side by side?